# How many different uses of the word "model" are there in mathematics?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, terminology, definition, model-theory

Is the name "model" as used in [model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) the same thing as the "model" used in geometry (e.g. [the models of hyperbolic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_geometry#Models_of_the_hyperbolic_plane))?

And is it possible to say that different probability spaces which induce the same distribution are "different models" of a random variable?

**Confusion:**
It seems somewhat plausible, since Alfred Tarski was strongly connected with both senses of the word ([at least for Euclidean geometry](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Euclidean+geometry#TarskiAxioms)). On the other hand, [the Wikipedia article about model theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_theory) is to me more confusing than helpful, giving statements like "model theory = algebraic geometry - fields" or "universal algebra + logic = model theory", when the opening paragraph seems to give a much more general description of what model theory is, one which would seem to also apply to fields like differential geometry or analysis: "A set of sentences in a formal language is called a theory; a model of a theory is a structure (e.g. an interpretation) that satisfies the sentences of that theory."

Comment: The first two are, I think, the same : a model of a certain geometry is a structure in which the axioms of this geometry are satisfied, just like a model in model theory. More to the point, they can both be used to show that some theories are not contradictory. I remember someone telling me that Riemann had discovered that negating the 5th axiom gave a coherent theory when he found a model for it

Comment: Could someone explain the downvotes? I am not familiar with mathematical logic so I am not sure how to use the terms accurately. And the descriptions of "algebraic geometry - fields" and "universal algebra + logic" given on Wikipedia would seem to restrict the use of the term to a less general context.